# Lambda runs but no console output

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to build a lambda function in AWS - when I go and test the function, it says it completes successfully but the expected results are not showing up (ie transcribe job or file in S3). I put code to look for errors but nothing is showing in console either

Have the files uploaded as a zip in what I believe is the right way - the root of the zip file has node modules and index.js

Also can see it firing in xray

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    var Parser = require('rss-parser');
    var request = require('request');
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var bucketName = 'transcribebucketkm';
    var bucketNameOut = 'transcribebucketkm-out';

    var parser = new Parser();
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var transcribeservice = new AWS.TranscribeService();

    AWS.config.update({region:'us-east-1'});
    var datetime = new Date
    var datetime = datetime.toISOString().slice(0,10) + ".mp3";
    var mediafileuri= "http://s3.amazonaws.com/transcribebucketkm/" + datetime

    parser.parseURL('https://bridgetown.podbean.com/feed.xml', function (err, feed) {
         console.log(err)
         request({ method: 'GET', url: feed.items[0].enclosure.url, encoding: null},function (err, response, body) {  
             console.log(err)
             console.log(body)
             s3.upload({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: datetime, Body: body}, function(err, data) {
                  console.log(data)
                  transcribeservice.startTranscriptionJob({LanguageCode: "en-US", Media:{MediaFileUri: mediafileuri}, MediaFormat: "mp3", TranscriptionJobName: datetime, OutputBucketName: bucketNameOut});
             });
         });
    });
}
```

Console does show only null - making me believe no errors

Comment: What permissions are in the role you've assigned to the function? It needs `log:...` permissions to send information to CloudWatch Logs. However, when running the function from the console, debug output _should_ appear in the console when the **Details** heading is expanded.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. I have uploaded an audio mp3 in a S3 bucket & have public access to it.

let myP = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      transcribeService.startTranscriptionJob(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err){
            rej(err);
          }else{
            res(data);
          }
        });
    });
    myP.then(
        result => callback(null, JSON.stringify(result)),
        error => callback(null, 'Error')
    );

There is no error but just returns null